# Replacement for Shimano Nexus 7 outer casing holder

Tags: shimano, nexus

I swapped my Nexus 7 sprocket with a new and the bracket apparently has a much larger diameter, so my cable is not stopped. The drawings that came along showed that I need an "outer casing holder" like http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/shimano-alfine-sl-s700-outer-casing-holder-unit-6tv-9806-prod32968/

Do you guys know of a work around? Or should I just go ahead and order it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got the CJNX40 or CJ8S40 bracket then you'll need the piece. So yeah, order it.

Frankly, if you just swapped the cog I don't understand why the cassette joint is different. But I'm assuming more happened than just the cog. Whatever the case, if the casing slot/area/thing on this bracket is bigger than the previous casing slot/area/thing then that holder unit makes up the difference.